# laravel 5.3 database notification customization

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating laravel 5.3 database notifications.I have created notifications as per video published on https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/10 , 
Now i want to add custom fields to the notification table as per my requirements.
Please help me how to pass custom data to notification and access it.

Comment: Having similar problem, anyone please help

Comment: found any solution ?

Comment: me too, seems that notifications are too young, or not enough well documented for use it effectively

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658694/69537

Answer (score -1):

When I needed to put custom fields to Notification, I'd just put on data field, as it is a Json field, works perfectly. Like this:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class TaskNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $message;

    /**
     * @param String $message
     */
    public function __construct($message=false)
    {
        if ($message)
            $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => $this->message,
            'link' => route('mymodel.show'),
            'task'=> 1, // This is one variable which I've created
            'done'=> 0 // This is one variable which I've created
        ];
    }
}
```