# Laravel: customize or extend notifications - database model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

IMHO, the current Database channel for saving notifications in Laravel is really bad design:

- You can't use foreign key cascades on items for cleaning up notifications of a deleted item for example
- Searching custom attributes in the `data` column (casted to Array) is not optimal

How would you go about extending the `DatabaseNotification` Model in vendor package?

I would like to add columns `event_id`, `question_id`, `user_id` (the user that created the notification) etc... to the default laravel `notifications` table

How do you override the `send` function to include more columns?

In:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/DatabaseChannel.php
```

The code:

```
class DatabaseChannel
{
 /**
  * Send the given notification.
  *
  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
  * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
  * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
  */
 public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
 {
    return $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('database')->create([
        'id' => $notification->id,
        'type' => get_class($notification),

      \\I want to add these
        'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id,
        'event_id' => $notification->type =='event' ? $notification->id : null, 
        'question_id' => $notification->type =='question' ? $notification->id : null,
      \\End adding new columns

        'data' => $this->getData($notifiable, $notification),
        'read_at' => null,
    ]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**To create a custom Notification Channel:**

First, create a Class in App\Notifications for example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class CustomDbChannel 
{

  public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
  {
    $data = $notification->toDatabase($notifiable);

    return $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('database')->create([
        'id' => $notification->id,

        //customize here
        'answer_id' => $data['answer_id'], //<-- comes from toDatabase() Method below
        'user_id'=> \Auth::user()->id,

        'type' => get_class($notification),
        'data' => $data,
        'read_at' => null,
    ]);
  }

}
```

Second, use this channel in the `via` method in the Notification class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

use App\Notifications\CustomDbChannel;

class NewAnswerPosted extends Notification
{
  private $answer;

  public function __construct($answer)
  {
    $this->answer = $answer;
  }

  public function via($notifiable)
  {
    return [CustomDbChannel::class]; //<-- important custom Channel defined here
  }

  public function toDatabase($notifiable)
  {
    return [
      'type' => 'some data',
      'title' => 'other data',
      'url' => 'other data',
      'answer_id' => $this->answer->id //<-- send the id here
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: how to get user information from notification variable?

Comment: In my case, for some reasons, native notifications table still in use...

Comment: Driver [App\Notifications\CustomDatabaseChannel] not supported

Comment: For me instead toDatabase(), toArray() worked

Comment: How would you select what table is used. For example for certain notifications I would like them to be saved in table that is in a different schema? is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

Create and use your own `Notification` model and `Notifiable` trait and then use your own Notifiable trait in your (User) models.

App\Notifiable.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable as BaseNotifiable;

trait Notifiable
{
    use BaseNotifiable;

    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Notification::class, 'notifiable')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

App\Notification.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

class Notification extends DatabaseNotification
{
    // ...
}
```

App\User.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I extended DatabaseNotification class and created `notifications` method with my own Notification model. and created custom Notifiable trait too. but after extending `notifications`  uuid is not workng its giving Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' error and its storing id as '' blank value. I tried `protected $keyType = 'string';` and `public $incrementing = false;` on Notification model also

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Make sure you use the `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait in your own trait as shown in the example.

Comment: Yes, I did that way

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had issue where notifications and notifiable models were on 2 separate mssql databases. And I easily fixed that by this example. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

An example for [@cweiske response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549147/7491725).

If you really need extends the `Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel` not creating a new Channel you can:

Extends the channel:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel as BaseDatabaseChannel;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class MyDatabaseChannel extends BaseDatabaseChannel
{
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $adminNotificationId = null;
        if (method_exists($notification, 'getAdminNotificationId')) {
            $adminNotificationId = $notification->getAdminNotificationId();
        }

        return $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('database')->create([
            'id' => $notification->id,
            'type' => get_class($notification),
            'data' => $this->getData($notifiable, $notification),

            // ** New custom field **
            'admin_notification_id' => $adminNotificationId,

            'read_at' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And register the `Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel` on application container again:

`app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel::class,
            App\Notifications\MyDatabaseChannel::class
        );
    }
}
```

Now when the `Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager` try `createDatabaseDriver` will return your registered database driver.

More one option to solve this problem!

Comment: The register part didn't work for me, but I found this article https://medium.com/@alouinimedamin/customize-your-database-notification-and-database-channel-in-laravel-576c8fa5f498 and got it working by passing `$this->app->make(..Mailer class..)` and `$this->app->make(..Markdown class..)`for my override mail channel class

Comment: What I wanted to change is how timestamps are stored in notifications table in SQL Server, and this has been the point. By adding `'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-d-m H:i:s.0')` and `'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-d-m H:i:s.0')` to the `create` function, it has been solved! Laravel documentation many times doesn't cover all situations, so... Thank you all!!

Answer (score 4):

Unlike "Bassem El Hachem", I wanted to keep the `database` keyword in the `via()` methods.

So in addition to a custom `DatabaseChannel`, I also wrote my own `ChannelManager` that returns my own `DatabaseChannel` in the `createDatabaseDriver()` method.

In my apps' `ServiceProvider::register()` method, I overwrote the singleton for the original ChannelManager class to return my custom manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject new columns' values on the model level by listening to the `creating` event.

1. Set your notification.

```php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class YourNotification extends Notification
{
    // ...

    public function toArray($notifiable): array
    {
        return [
            'new_column' => 'value',
            'serializable_data' => $serializable_data,
        ];
    }
}
```

2. Create your own notification model and edit what is being inserted.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

class Notification extends DatabaseNotification
{
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::creating(function (Notification $notification) {
            $data = $notification->data;

            $notification->new_column = $data['new_column'];
            unset($data['new_column']);

            $notification->data = $data;
        });
    }
}
```

3. Override the relationship on the user model.

```php
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Notification::class, 'notifiable')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by customizing notification class:

create the class for this action:

```
artisan make:notification NewQuestion
```

inside it:

```
public function __construct($user,$question)
    {
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->question=$question;
    }


...

    public function toDatabase($notifiable){
        $data=[
            'question'=>$this->(array)$this->question->getAttributes(),
            'user'=>$this->(array)$this->user->getAttributes()
        ];

        return $data;
    }
```

then you can access proper data in view or controller like this:

```
@if($notification->type=='App\Notifications\UserRegistered')
<a href="{!!route('question.show',$notification->data['question']['id'])!!}">New question from {{$notification->data['user']['name']}}</a>
@endif
```