# How to add custom column for laravel 'notifications' table

Tags: notifications, laravel-5.3

I want to add `ref_no` column to `notifications` table. I have `ref_no` column in `appointments` table. When some one add a new appointment i wanna update `ref_no` columns in `both tables`. Click on notifications panel i wanna open all `appointments` table ( not notifications). When click on a `appointment` i wanna delete the relevant row `notifications` table.

```
appointments table

id | date | ref_no
```

default `notifications` table with added `ref_no` column

```
id | type | notifiable_id | notifiable_type | data | read_at | created_at | updated_at | ref_no
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I wanted to add custom relations to notifications and am not sure if this is ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658694/69537