# How to notify the person based on his post in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I was able to create a `Notification` table using migration. Also I can save notification if a user(X) replies to the post of user(Y). Now, the problem is, I want to send the notification to user(Y), but then, the `notifiable_id` saves the id of user(X). How can user(Y) receive the notification then?

```
 Auth::user()->notify(new PostNotif());
```

Example:

user(X) ID is : 12 and, 
user(Y) ID is : 24

The notifications table looks like this:

```
type                          notifiable_id  notifiable_type 
App\Notifications\PostNotif       12              App\User
```

I expected that the notifiable_id should be the ID of user(Y) which is 24 and not 12.

Since, the user(Y) submitted a post and user(X) responded to that post, how can user(Y) be notified in this case?

EDIT

Also, I expect two IDs to be inserted into the database notification. One for the user who created the post and the other for the one who responded to the post.

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this table structure to send notification,

`type` `Notification_id` `sender_id` `receiver_id`

you can store `userX` in sender_id and `userY` in receiver_id, wise a versa.

I hope it works.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. But, how to save `sender_id` and `receiver_id` into the database since, notify method does not include saving of data other than the default fields.

Comment: I tried this already but it returns null when executing the `Auth::user()->notify(new PostNotif());`

Comment: Add new field sender_id and receiver_id in notification table,

so when you call send notification 
ex: X is sender then store X id in sender_id and Y (multiple user) is receiver then you have to store multiple notification in this table

Comment: yeah. thank you. I found this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646085/laravel-5-4-5-3-customize-or-extend-notifications-database-model