# How to add Softdeletes to Notifications Table laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel default database notifications, I want to add *softdelete* to notifications table.

I have created a migration with softdelete which has added ***deleted_at*** column to the notifications table. The problem is I have to add '***use SoftDeletes***' to notifications model(*according to laravel docs*) but cannot find the notifications model.

```
 $table->softDeletes();
```

I tried adding '***use SoftDeletes***' to ***HasDatabaseNotifications*** trait but it still deletes the row. Is there another way to add *softdelete* to notifications table. TIA

Answer (score 1):

In your model at top before start class **use**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

After class

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

     /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dilip Hirapara, but I cannot find the Notification Model beacause I am using default laravel notifications

Comment: Have you check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-use-custom-database-notification-model or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646085/laravel-5-4-5-3-customize-or-extend-notifications-database-model

Comment: both question and answer from Kamal Khan.

Comment: I looked at these threads but they are different, my problem is that I cannot find the notification model where I have to use softdelete, may be there's no option of soft deleting in laravel notifications

Comment: I think you need  to override your notification model as @Kamal Khan did. check your `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` if Notifiable class exists then you may override it, and after you can use it as model like I explain soft delete. First follow the @Kamal Khan answer check it possible. I really don't know about notification can be softdelete or not but he followed to changes in model so might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, I hope it will be useful for you and other friends

App\Classes\MyDatabaseNotification.php

```
namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

class MyDatabaseNotification extends DatabaseNotification
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

App\Classes\MyNotifiable.php

```
namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

trait MyNotifiable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(MyDatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

App\User.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Classes\MyNotifiable;
...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use MyNotifiable;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue:

1. Create a migration to add a `deleted_at` column to notifications table:

   ```
   /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->softDeletes();
       });
   }

   /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->dropColumn(['deleted_at']);
       });
   }
   ```
2. Create a new model extending the `DatabaseNotification` model class and add the `SoftDeletes` trait. The `DatabaseNotification` class extends the model class, so it's basically just a model:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

   class Notification extends DatabaseNotification
   {
       use SoftDeletes;
       ...
   ```
3. Optionally create a `NotificatonController` class and implement the delete function. You have to use your new `Notification` class as a param. Using the original `DatabaseNotification` class will not work for soft deletion:

   ```
   class NotificationsController extends Controller
   {
       ...

       /**
        * @param  Notification  $notification
        * @return JsonResponse
        */
        public function delete(Notification $notification)
        {
            $notification->delete();

            return new JsonResponse(null, 204);
        }

        ...
   }
   ```